# Getting albums covers with facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, asynccallback

I'm trying to fetch albums list from facebook via JavaScript and Graph API. I'm doing it like this:

```
FB.api('/me/albums', function(response){
    //
});
```

Album covers coming back as photo id, not a url that I can insert into html. So, I need to get a urls in second step. But, by application design, I can't get urls later and insert images. I need to return a complete data object with album propereties (id, name, cover url). My last try is listed below:

```
FB.api('/me/albums', { fields : 'id,name,count,cover_photo' }, function(response){

    if (!response || response.error) {
        callback.call(false);
        return;
    };

    var parsed = $(response.data).map(function(){

        if (this.count > 0) {

            var result = {
                aid : this.id,
                title : this.name,
                cover : this.cover_photo
            };

            return result;
        };
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {

        (function(i){

            FB.api('/' + parsed[i].cover, { type : 'album' }, function(response){
                parsed[i].thumb = response.picture;
            });

        })(i);

    };

    callback.call(parsed);
});
```

The problem is that the loop is not waiting for cover queries and going forward, leaving return  object without cover urls. I think it's can not be so difficult to do, but I can't find the solution long enough. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.getAlbums = function() {
FB.api({
     method: 'fql.multiquery',
     queries: {
        query1: 'select aid,name,link,photo_count,cover_object_id from album where owner = me()',
        query2: 'SELECT pid,src FROM photo WHERE object_id  IN (SELECT cover_object_id FROM #query1)'
     }
    },
    function(response) {
        var parsed = new Array();
        $(response[0].fql_result_set).each(function(index,value){
                var result = {
            aid : value.aid,
            title : value.name,
            cover : response[1].fql_result_set[index].src,
                            link :value.link
        };
                parsed.push(result);
        })
    getdata(parsed);
});
```

};

Apped your album detail using

```
function getdata(data){

$(data).each(function(index,value){
    // console.log(value.aid + ' - '+ value.cover+ ' - '+ value.title );
    $("#fb_albumb").append('<h3>'+ value.title +'</h3><a href="'+ value.link  +'" target="_blank" ><img src="'+ value.cover +'" title="'+ value.title +'" /></a><br/>');
})
```

}

HTML

```
<fb:login-button scope="user_photos" onlogin="getAlbums()">Grant Permissions to Allow access to Photos and Albums</fb:login-button>
```

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that the loop is not waiting for cover queries and going forward, leaving return object without cover urls.

Of course, because FB.api is an *asynchronous* method.

> I think it's can not be so difficult to do, but I can't find the solution long enough.

You’d have to use a callback function for your second FB.api calls in the loop as well, and implement a counter in it – when this counter shows that all the requests are done, *then* you can pass the data on to somewhere else (or use it right there in that function, because “returning” it will not work – because the method is asynchronous).

Maybe better to use FQL right away, because there you could kind of “join” the necessary data together and get it all in just one call; something like a multiquery as f.e.

```
{
  "q1" : "SELECT aid, name, cover_object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me()",
  "q2" : "SELECT aid, src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id IN
                 (SELECT cover_object_id FROM #q1)"
}
```

([Test this query in the Graph API explorer.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%7B%20%22q1%22%20%3A%20%22SELECT%20aid%2C%20name%2C%20cover_object_id%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20owner%20%3D%20me%28%29%22%2C%20%22q2%22%20%3A%20%22SELECT%20aid%2C%20src_big%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20object_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20cover_object_id%20FROM%20%23q1%29%22%20%7D#q1%29%22%20%7D))